# There is a pluralisation error on the Documentation help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, plurals

There's a stray ***s*** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-voting):

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter an example***s*** that is especially useful, or a topic request you want to see a response to.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: [*Jeff, he will come to your house bludgeon you to death with a giant S! Be prepared :P*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791)

Comment: @Rizier123 In my defence, in this case it's *totally static copy*. The usual excuses for pluralisation bugs don't apply.

Comment: I would say, descriptive title.

Comment: "*The usual excuses for pluralisation bugs don't apply.*" -- tell that to Jeff when you open the door, and let me know what he says.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: OP was last seen 2 hours ago ... I don't think it worked.

Comment: Oh, the irony....    "There **are** **an** pluralisation error**s**..."

Comment: I assumed the error in the title was deliberate.

Comment: It always is (cc @DeepSpace)...

Comment: This was not a case of Muphry's Law.

Comment: I can't unsee the death of subtlety in this comment thread and it makes me very sad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, traditional excuses don't apply. I'll have to come up with some new ones...

But in the meantime, this is fixed!